# Mongoose by default saving floats with zero after decimal as integers ( 0.0 as 0 )

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a schema-less Model i.e. a blank schema as :

```
const NewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

});
```

The reason I need this is, I am expecting unstructured and unexpected fields as of now during the development phase of my project.

```
var myModel = new Mongoose.model('myModel', NewSchema)
```

When it receives a float value like 0.1, it is stored as a "Double" in mongoDB. The issue is when it receives something like 1.0 or 0.0 which is saving by default as 1 and 0.

```
myModel.create({
  "videoLength" : 0.0
})
```

Result in database.

```
{
 "videoLength" : 0 (Int32)
}
```

Expectation is, for it to be saved as 1.0 and 0.0 as type Double. I know this is possible by specifying types in Schema but **how to do this without specifying the fields with types explicitly in schema.**

Comment: In JS you cannot have all trailing zeros after a decimal and maintain the datatype as number at the same time (Essentially 1.00000 is ~ 1). If the usecase is to maintain that precision -which can be achieved by converting it to string (a trade-off) and storing it as that. Using `.toFixed()` `toPrecision()`.